# Rails Rpec InvalidCrossOriginRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, xss

I have a test in rspec for a destroy that returns the following:

`ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest:
       Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.`

I can run the destroy just fine thru the UI but when it gets tested I get the above warning. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Is your `destroy` request supposed to be an AJAX request? If so, you can assign the `xhr` option to true.

```
get some_path, xhr: true
```